# How to get memsite id when account add failed in fastlink

Tags: yodlee

Hi i am using yodlee fastlink integration and my question is when user add account and it failed how i will get memsiteaccount id.

i read all documents but there is no way mention 
[yodlee API's](https://developer.yodlee.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [getAllSiteAccounts](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getAllSiteAccounts) API to get all the added accounts successful as well as unsuccessful.